# I want to check if a response attribute of one http request exits in another http request as well. How can I do that?

Tags: jmeter

HTTP request
 .. regular expression to pick up a token "PostID"

[image]

HTTP request
 ..Beanshell assertion to verify if ${PostID} exists in the response

[image]

I am using the while controller to loop the request till PostID is found

while condition being  ${__javaScript("${count}" != 1)}

Beanshell assertion is failing though I see the PostID in the response of "FetchSentPost" request

[image]

I need the while loop to end on the first encounter of Post ID in the HTTP request "FetchSentPost"

Where Am I going wrong?

Comment: instead of pattern matching, try with `contains` method of String. eg: `str.contains(ID)` in your case, which returns `True/False`. examples here http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-contains-examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes made in the script.

1. Condition must be changed to `${__javaScript(${count} != 1)}`. No double quotes.
2. In BeanShell Assertion, instead of `count += 1`, you must assign count value using vars.put as follows `vars.put("count", 1);`

As Dmitri mentioned, other mistake is:

```
String ID = vars.get("PostID");
```

Related to `contains` vs `regex matching`, try both after making above changes. I tried with `contains`, it is working.

---

Using `contains`:

```
while(!str.contains(ID)){
  vars.put("count", 1);
}
```

Comment: Declared a user defined variable 'PostIdFound' outside the loop with value false and used if condition to change it to true. This solved the problem. Thank you both @Naveen

Comment: I believe the guy has observed an exception right at this line `vars.put("count", 1);` as the method is supposed to take strings only

Comment: I answered it once I verified in my system. It is working with int value.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your Beanshell script:

```
String ID = vars.get(PostID);
                     ^^^^^^
```

should be

```
 String ID = vars.get("PostID");
```

Going forward you can add [debug();](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive to the beginning of your JMeter script for troubleshooting.  I would also recommend switching to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language, Groovy performs much better and more Java-compliant.

Comment: thank you but there are few other script issues. I had to declared a user defined variable 'PostIdFound' outside the loop with value false and used if condition to change it to true. This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

created a user defined variable 'PostIdFound' with value 'False' outside the while loop.

Changed the while condition to ${__javaScript(${PostIdFound} != true)}

and then changed the BeanShell script as follows

```
import java.util.regex;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String ID = vars.get("PostID");
String str= SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.get("PostIdFound");
if(str.contains(ID)){
vars.put("PostIdFound","true");
}
```

Issue Resolved. Thankyou @Dmitri T and @Naveen for the help